# OpenMP taskloop inside task

Tags: c++, task, openmp, parallel.for

I am using the OpenMP `taskloop` construct inside a `task` construct:

```cpp
double compute(int input) {
  int array[4] = {0};
  double value = input;

  #pragma omp taskloop private(value)
  for(int i=0; i<5000000; i++) {                                                                                                       
    // random computation, the result is not meaningful
    value *= std::tgamma(std::exp(std::cos(std::sin(value)*std::cos(value))));
    int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
    array[tid] ++;
  }

  for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    printf("array[%d] = %d ", i, array[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");

  return value;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  omp_set_nested(1);
  omp_set_num_threads(4);  // 4 cores on my machine

  #pragma omp parallel 
  {
    #pragma omp single
    {
      #pragma omp task
      { compute(omp_get_thread_num()); }
    }
  }                                                                                                     
 }
```

The resulting array is all 0. However, if I change the `taskloop` to `parallel for`:

```
  #pragma omp parallel for private(value)
  for(int i=0; i<5000000; i++) {
    value *= std::tgamma(std::exp(std::cos(std::sin(value)*std::cos(value))));
    int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
    array[tid] ++; 
  }
```

Then the result of the array is 1250000 for each index. Is there anything wrong in my use of `taskloop` construct?

Comment: Maybe try explicitly stating that the array is shared. I think there are only two reasons for why it might not be working. The function might not be running or there is a copy of the array that is getting modified. I haven't used tasks before but it seems that they have a special data sharing.

Comment: maybe your omp implementation use `shared(none)` for default. try printing the `array` base address in each iteration to see if it varies from the original adress

Comment: @Warpstar22 that is indeed what is wrong. You should write it up as an answer.

Comment: @Tes making `value` private without initializing it is also wrong, even though you don’t use that result here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well by @Cimbali's confirmation, it seems that your issue is that the array is not being shared among threads. Since you did not explicitly say that the variable array is shared or private, OpenMP will determine it by its rules. Tasks have a special data sharing attribute compared to parallel for. I couldn't find anything that specifies the rules explicitly. [This](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/820-7883/6nj43o69j/index.html) was the best I could find. Try specifying a default clause and that the array variable is shared.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Data-Sharing Attribute Rules](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu103.html) this is the expected behaviour:

"In a task generating construct, if no **default** clause is present, a variable for which the data-sharing attribute is not determined by the rules above is **firstprivate**."

BTW: It is always recommended to use **default(none)**, and you will be forced to define data-sharing rules explicitly.